# Index vs. Unique Key in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have the following table that serves to join 3 tables:

```
ClientID int
BlogID  int
MentionID   int
```

Assuming that queries will always come via ClientID, I can create 1 multi-column index (ClientID, BlogID, MentionID).

The question is, should I create it as a clustered index or a unique key? I understand a clustered index stores the data on its leaf nodes. Of course, in this case, the index **is** the data, so I don't know if SQL Server will duplicate the data or not. Be that as it may, I can't find anything on MSDN about the significance of using "unique key".

How does this differ from Type = Index & IsUnique = yes?

Can someone tell me the advantages each way?

Comment: Which columns should be unique?

Comment: The 3 together. Any single column, not.

Comment: @IanC: just out of curiosity, what does the table describe? Can one `MentionID` belong to more than one client or more than one blog?

Comment: @Quassnoi it describes how one mention is of a client and may be on a blog. A mention can only connect to 1 client and possibly one blog. Hmmm - I have the column order wrong.

Comment: @IanC: column order does not matter much as such, but why would you want a unique constraint on all three columns? I believe only `MentionID` should be unique, since it connects to only one client and only one blog.

Comment: Quassnoi I meant column order purely from the point of view of MS SQL Server Management Studio's design constraints on creating composite clustered indexes (ie., clicking the key icon). By "all 3 columns" I mean that all 3 columns **together** are unique. Not each column.

Comment: @Quassnoi I have concluded the best is this: unique clustered index on MentionID, plus relationship to Mentions, creating a 1:1 relationship. Index on ClientID. If I need to query from Blogs, then index on BlogID. Simple :)

Comment: @IanC: can you have two record with the same `MentionID` in the table, referring to different clients or blogs?

Comment: @Quassnoi Although theoretically possible, system design will prevent that from happening.

Comment: @IanC: probably it's better to declare `MentionID` as `UNIQUE` then?

Comment: @Quassnoi yes... in comment 7 in this list, I say "unique clustered index on MentionID" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are asking for the difference among:

```
 MYTABLE
 id integer primary key autoincrement
 clientid integer
 blogid integer
 mentionid integer
 -- with a unique composite index on (clientid, blogid, mentionid) and three foreign key constraints
```

and

```
 MYTABLE
 clientid 
 blogid
 mentionid
 -- with a composite primary key on (clientid, blogid, mentionid) and three foreign key constraints
```

and

```
 MYTABLE
 id integer primary key autoincrement
  clientid integer
  blogid integer
  mentionid integer
  with an index on clientid and also an index on blogid and the three foreign key constraints
```

In the first, you have the index on the integer primary key and also the alternative unique index on the triad.  If the second, you have only the unique index on the triadic primary key. In the third, you have a unique index on the integer primary key and two other non-unique indexes, one on clientid and the other on blogid.

The performance gain with the second option's marginally greater efficiency would be *de minimis*, and so I'd base the decision on other factors. The third is the most flexible in terms of queries and offers greater simplicity of coding; it offers the benefit of indexes on client and blog both, in case you wanted to have a query with blog, not client, in the WHERE clause. As for coding, some GUI tools and middleware have trouble with multi-part primary keys, and your update/insert/delete logic will be simpler when it has to deal with a single integer PK column.  I have found that code simplicity and ease of maintenance are far better things than a few seconds or only a few fractions of seconds of improvement in query response time.

Answer (score 4):

Clustered index is "the table itself", that is, index nodes are arranged in a tree, and its leaf nodes contains row data. Clustered index doesn't have to be declared as unique (though it usually is); if it is not unique, the server implicitly adds a "uniqalizer" to this index, so that each row is uniquely identified.

Other indexes store clustered index value as their leaf nodes (and possibly some other columns if they are included with INCLUDE clause in CREATE INDEX staetment).

Any index might be decalred as unique, so the server would perform an additional check to prevent duplicate values forom getting into the table.

Answer (score 1):

- A `unique index`, a `unique key` and
  a `unique constraint` are basically
  the same thing.  They result in an
  index that enforces uniqueness.
- Clustered means that the index
  becomes the table itself.  It's good
  to have a clustered index, otherwise
  the table hangs around in an
  unordered heap.

Unique and clustered are unrelated properties.  You can combine them in any way you like.  So in your case, I'd create a unique clustered index.  The normal way to do that is by creating the index as a `clustered primary key`.

Answer (score 1):

The data will **not** be duplicated if you create a clustered unique index on your three columns.

The unique clustered index will **be** the data - and the index at the same time :-)

Since this is a three-way join table, this clustered index probably does make a lot of sense. I'd say: go for it!

Answer (score 1):

`UNIQUE INDEX` and `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` are somewhat different concepts.

- `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` is a logical concept and means "make sure this column is unique, no matter how"
- `UNIQUE INDEX` is a physical concept and means "create a `B-Tree` index on this column and fail whenever duplicates are inserted there"

The latter implies the former but not vice versa.

For instance, in `Oracle`, if you have a non-unique index on `col1`:

- `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX (col1)` will fail and say "these columns are already indexed"
- `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE(col1)` will succeed and use the existing index to police the constraint.

Use `CONSTRAINT` if you just want the column to be unique and `INDEX` if you know a `B-Tree` index is what you want (to speed up searches etc).

Comment: Aren't indexes always unique and "unique index" is really misname of "unique index keys"?

Comment: @vgv8: internally, all indexes are unique indeed. `UNIQUE` means all *explicit* keys (provided in the in the index definition) are unique. If they are not, some kind of uniquifier (clustered key / clustered key with uniquifier / `RID`) is implicitly appended to the index keys.

Comment: @Quassnoi Surely adding a unique constraint to a column that is not already indexed will cause a unique index to be added? How else can the RDBMS determine if the values are unique.
It's interesting you answered this--I wasn't asking about constraints :)

Comment: @IanC: with current implementations of the systems, yes. However, this (theoretically) can be changed in the future. More than that: the indexes can be of different types, and by using `CONSTRAINT` you let the system choose the type. I answered this because you asked about `index vs. key` and key is a logical thing too (and even just a synonym for `CONSTRAINT` in several systems).

Comment: @Quassnoi as usual, I appreciate your answer. I do see your point. From a technical perspective, a constraint is technically correct if the only requirement is uniqueness. Interesting point. And, as you said, if one is querying against the column, then a unique index (I guess without any constraint although, given the logic, one could argue this) is the way to go.

Comment: @Quassnoi are you saying than in SQL Server, if I say "Type - Unique Key", a constraint, not an "index" will be added?

Comment: @IanC: right. You didn't answer which column sets you want to be unique.

Comment: @IanC: yes, it will expand into `CONSTRAINT UNIQUE`. You may click on `Generate Change Script` in the bottom of context menu and see actual `SQL` that will be used to create the table.

Comment: @Quassnoi I answered now: all 3, not any 1.

Comment: @Quassnoi wow, you are right - SQL Server added a constraint. Nice. So at least I can still use the visual editor - quicker that writing a script. You should publish a blog on SQL. In the areas I really know well, I have thought about doing this myself.

Comment: @IanC: if you open my profile, you will see a link to the blog. But just in case you're too lazy: http://explainextended.com